# Tooltipster initializes but no display on hover or click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltipster

I have been using Cluetip for 8 years. Was asked to spiff up the tips and realized it was abandonded 5 years ago. Tooltipster looks like its actively maintained and feature complete.

I have included the css and js files, no error on loading.

My html is generated by an xslt process but the html looks OK

```
<span class="handShift" data-tooltip-content="#ad1e88"> ⇉ </span>
<div class="tooltip_templates" style="display:none"><span class="tip" id="ad1e88"><span class="clueTitle">Handshift:</span><span class="clueNote">unknown</span></span></div>

<span class="handShift" data-tooltip-content="#ad1e92"> ⇉ </span>
<div class="tooltip_templates" style="display:none"><span class="tip" id="ad1e92"><span class="clueTitle">Handshift:</span><span class="clueNote">Mary Baker Eddy</span></span></div>
```

my js init call is

```
$('span.handShift').tooltipster({
      animation: 'fade',
     delay: 200,
     trigger: 'click',
     debug:true

  });
```

Once the page loads the two span.handShift elements have "tooltipstered" added to the class attribute.

I'm using the data-tooltip-content to specify what html is in the tip but I tried using the title attribute with the same results.

When I click on the text in the span.handShift the element identified with the data-tooltip-content attribute disapears from the DOM, no tip is displayed, no error in the console.  The element never returns,that I can see. Obviously something is going on as the span is removed from the DOM, but its not what is expected?

I'm using jquery 2.1.4

Comment: Tried a few hacks and gave up. I'm pretty sure the plugin doesn't like that fact that the parent html is in an iframe or that the parent div has an absolute position.  Anyway I made a quick change to QTip2 and it works out of the box. Also has builtin support for a close icon which I was going to have to hand roll for tooltipster.  Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

I've tested, your code works.

cf my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/405260/

Don't forget to include the main JS :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.js"></script>
```